# Can a sitemap file be php?

Tags: php, xml, seo

I'm fairly new to search engine optimization. But, I've heard that sitemaps can drastically improve SEO. I know that the sitemap file has to be in xml format. But, the content of my site is very dynamic. That being said, I need to query the DB to find out how the content has changed as time goes on. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once("functions.php");
connect();

//  Query the DB to get the past season MLB teams   
$query  =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM past_season_team_articles") or die(mysql_error());
$count  =   mysql_num_rows($query);
$i      =   0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
    $team[$i]   =   $row['team'];
    $year[$i]   =   $row['year'];   

    $i++;
}
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<?php
 // Loop thru the array and echo out the MLB teams
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
?>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.sportannica.com/teams.php?team=<?php echo $team[$i]; ?>&amp;year=<?    php echo $year[$i]; ?></loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
<?php
}
?>
</urlset>
```

Comment: What's your question/problem?

Comment: I just want to know if a sitemap file can be a php file

Comment: no, the PHP file will generate the sitemap either in xml, html etc

Comment: So how do I make my sitemap file dynamic? It wont do much good if it's hard coded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use .htaccess (both under Apache and under IIS using helicon) to map requests to sitemap.xml to sitemap.php which returns a 'live' sitemap.
Just had a quick look at your code but that looks about right, you just need to map the rewrite.

Comment: Well, what do I do from here? How do I map the rewrite with the .htaccess file?

Comment: Rewrites are covered extensively on StackOverflow and elsewhere, and since it can be dependent on your configuration I'm not going to provide samples which may be useless to you. Google .htaccess or basic url rewriting, or check the mod-rewrite tag on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, I've messed around with modrewrite a bit before. I used it to make the links to some of my site's pages cleaner and more user friendly. But, the code that I wrote on my question looks correct? I just need to use the .htaccess file so that the contents of the sitemap.php are loaded into sitemap.xml?

Comment: Yep, that's right. Exactly the same type of rename as with a 'regular' human-readable page.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I'll just create a blank sitemap.xml file with nothing in it. And then configure the .htaccess file so that xml file is populated with the content echoes out in the php file.

Comment: You don't need a blank sitemap.xml file, just the sitemap.php. The rewrite basically makes sitemap.php appear to any request as if it was sitemap.xml :)

Comment: Cool. So, I'll just keep the sitemap.php file as it and put RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache or NginX you can use rewrite rules to process requests for your sitemap file to a PHP script that generates the sitemap contents instead, together with the appropriate headers.

Could be nice if you provide more details about your setup.

Comment: Um, I don't know too much about the setup of the server that hosts my site. I think that it's Cent OS. But, beyond that, I don't know too much. I've messed around with the .htaccess file before to make cleaner urls. But, I quit for now just because when I cleaned up the urls, the external css and js files weren't loading properly. Kind of a newbie to this...

Answer (score 0):

You have try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<?php

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
    echo "<url><loc>http://www.sportannica.com/teams.php?team=$row['team']&amp;year=$row['year']</loc>";
    echo " <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>";
}
?>
</urlset>
```